# Proof using dot and cross product.

Tags: vectors, proof-explanation, cross-product

I am looking at a derivation of the parallel axis theorem in a book. The photo is below

[image]

I'm not sure why but I just cannot figure out how they got from line 2 to line 3. I have thought through all of the properties I know (I have expanded and used the vector triple product, the cyclic permutations of scalar triple product etc) but I cannot seem to figure out that step.

Would very much appreciate if someone could enlighten me as to what property/rule was used here.

Comment: lagrange's identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (a \times b) \cdot (c \times d) = \varepsilon_{kij} a_i b_j \varepsilon_{klm} c_l d_m = (\delta_{il} \delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{kl}) a_i b_j c_l d_m = (a \cdot c)(b \cdot d) - (a \cdot d)(b \cdot c),  $$
so in this case,
$$ \lVert \hat{n} \times (r-a) \rVert^2 = \lVert \hat{n} \rVert^2 \lVert r-a \rVert^2 - (\hat{n} \cdot (r-a))^2.  $$

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought I would be OK with the rest of the proof but I have also gotten stuck on the penultimate line. I have read the note below the proof several times but I don't see how it applies as you do not have an independent vector r in the integral that is the third from last line. How can the result of integrating the vector r with respect to the mass be used when inyegrating the magnitude of r or when integrating the dot product of a with r?

Comment: If it's the same as [this edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FMahjlDKpt4C&lpg=PA119&ots=ZkESB-eo2D&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the solution manual to Riley, Hobson and Bence, the definition of $I_0$ becomes $ \int (r^2-(n \cdot r)^2) \, dm $, which deals with the terms with two $r$s, and linearity of the integral gives $\int a \cdot r \, dm = a \cdot \int r \, dm$, which is what happens to the linear terms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still have questions about this so I feel I should make a new post, but thank you for all of your insights!